# I want to call the servlet when I click on a dropdown option?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have to get the data in a `DropDown` on choosing the option from another `DropDown`and the data should come from a database to the `DropDown`.

```
ResultSet rs2=st.executeQuery("select cmpny from data2 where name='" + trendname + "'");
```

I wrote the database code using jstl but for the `where` clause I have to take from `DropDown` value.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass selected option to servlet if you put select tag in a form tag

for example :

```
  <form action="YourServlet" method="post">
    <select name="trendname">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
         </select>
</form>
```

and in your doPost method get the selected value

```
String trendname  =  request.getParameter("trendname");
```

Comment: it is not working @TAHA     u can suggest me another one